# Libgdx How to make 2D bounce ball with shadow illusion?

Tags: libgdx

Libgdx How to make 2D bounce ball with shadow illusion?
I want to make a ball bounce up and down with shadow which scaled in out
[Like This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLWpkFLMidk)

Comment: update the link for the youtube video..it's broken

Comment: @george the link has been fixed. For the future- this is SO... Edit away!

Comment: did you start something ? i recommend to use box2d for the bouncing ball, and for the shadow you can use a texture inside a sprite and resize it in proprtion of the distance between the ball and the ground

Comment: I tried to scale the shadow texture according to distance,but still not appear exactly as the video link

Comment: I used scene2d actors but the position and scale of the shadow is not appear in a proper way.can you give me snippet code?

Comment: First of all wellcome on SO. You need to provide some code and SO will help you to get stuff working as you whish. Take a look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can use box2dLights for the shadow and box2d for the ball. scale the shadow depending on the ball position as regards to the ground